# Dreamweaver: How to display recordsets in a single row without using a table

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, dreamweaver, records

I am a Dreamweaver CS5 and MySQL user, a I am trying to implement an online store where customers can view and buy images or video. I have a table on the SQL server that will keep track of all information about pictures. i.e., length, format, title, album, price, etc. I know how to get data to be displayed and how to create the recordset and pass parameters that are needed when the customers do their search / shopping.

My question is... How do I get the RESULTS of the data, or the Recordset to display in a custom format other than a table. For an example Dreamweaver provided dynamic tables to display results or dynamic text.

```
Field A | Field B | Field C | Field D | Field E | Field F |          Field G |
122       Orange     48 x 29    Color    19.99    Jones Photography  picture.gif
```

The above is how Dreamweaver, and how I know that data can be displayed.
How do I display it like this below:

```
Record 1                 Record 2           Record 3 (Same format), and so on....
Field G (Picture.gif)    Field G
Field A                  Field A
Field B                  Field B
Field C                  Field C
Field D                  Field D
Field E
```

How do I display my records or results in this format?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following:

```
<style>
div.rsColumn{
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
</style>
<?php do { ?>
<div class="rsColumn">
    <?php echo $row_Recordset1['Column1']; ?><br />
    <?php echo $row_Recordset1['Column2']; ?><br />
    <?php echo $row_Recordset1['Column3']; ?><br />
    <?php echo $row_Recordset1['ColumnLast']; ?>
</div>
<?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
```

What this code does is to loop over a DIV tag that contains output for each row in the recordset in a "column" type of output. The border styling is to show where your data blocks are, remove/update as necessary.

You'll likely run into issues where the number of columns is too wide for you content area, and then you may want to move to float:left for the CSS selector rather than display:inline-block. And you may run into issues with column heights (trying to make DIV have the same height when the data output varies greatly (think product details that could be a single short sentence or twenty long paragraphs), that would be a CSS question to ask separately (or search first, of course).

Note: the default Dreamwavqer code will run through a recordset loop code once even if the recordset has no rows in the result, so you'll need to wrap this code with a Show Region -> Show If Recordset Is Not Empty